# Multiplying BigInteger by Double

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

My Physics teacher gave the class a hard task. I'm trying to create a program that will calculate some things for me. At a certain point I need to multiply an amount of molecules by a percentage. Ulong can't hold numbers as large as 6022 * 10 ^ 19, so I have to use BigInteger from .net 4.0. However multiplication cannot be applied to BigInteger and double. I only need the whole number. Is there any way to bypass this?
The code is as follows:

```
private static BigInteger pencapmoles = BigInteger.Pow(6022/9, 19);
private static BigInteger inkmoles = pencapmoles;
private static BigInteger tries = 0;
private static BigInteger molesinbucket = BigInteger.Pow(26761768, 19);
private static double percentage;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (inkmoles > 1) 
    {
        percentage = (double)(inkmoles / molesinbucket);
        inkmoles = pencapmoles * percentage;
        tries++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"It only took us {tries} tries.");
}
```

Comment: Cast the `percentage` to `BigInteger`. Like this `inkmoles = pencapmoles * (BigInteger) percentage;`

Comment: Why are you using BigInteger? These are all physical quantities (except for `tries`) which could easily be represented as doubles.

Comment: Just use doubles for all physical quantities. Use integers only for quantities where you know **exactly** how many of a thing there are.

Comment: Remember you can use scientific notation with doubles: `double avogadro = 6.022E23;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using doubles solved my problem. I never thought they could hold such large values.

Comment: Doubles can hold values with 15 significant decimal places up to around 10 to the 308th power.  **Use doubles for physics problems**.  Use decimals for money problems; use integers when you have an *exact* integer number of a thing.

Comment: I have answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76040289/1641247

Answer (score 4):

You would be better off switching all computations either to `double` or to `BigInteger`. C# `double` has enough range to hold values a lot greater than 10<sup>19</sup>, but the answer is going to have a slight imprecision. It is a near certainty that it is going to be enough for the purposes of solvind your task.

If you switch to `BigInteger`, multiply first, and then do the division:

```
inkmoles = (inkmoles * pencapmoles) / molesinbucket;
```