# How to multiply a BigInteger with a decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

How to multiply a BigInteger with a decimal in C#?

```
var bi = new BigInteger(1000);
var d = 0.9m;
// HowTo:
var res = BigInteger.Multiply(bi, d); // res = 900
```

Of course, the result should be *floored* down to the previous full integer value.

There is a practical background, but in regards to the posted "duplicate", I'm also interested into an answer to the question from a theoretical point of view. I'm not looking for a workaround by using double instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying BigInteger by Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506473/multiplying-biginteger-by-double)

Comment: @FrankerZ: Have you read the answer before posting this comment? It is most probably no duplicate.

Comment: I have read said answer. Why wont that work for you?

Comment: Because "It is a near certainty that it is going to be enough for the purposes of solvind your task" just does not do it for us. I'm looking for an answer to my question, not for a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can represent `decimal` as fraction

```
(BigInteger numerator, BigInteger denominator) Fraction(decimal d) {
    int[] bits = decimal.GetBits(d);
    BigInteger numerator = (1 - ((bits[3] >> 30) & 2)) *
                           unchecked(((BigInteger)(uint)bits[2] << 64) |
                                     ((BigInteger)(uint)bits[1] << 32) |
                                      (BigInteger)(uint)bits[0]);
    BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.Pow(10, (bits[3] >> 16) & 0xff);
    return (numerator, denominator);
}
```

Then you can multiply `BigInteger` to numerator and divide by denominator:

```
var bi = new BigInteger(1000);
var d = 0.9m;
var f = Fraction(d);
var res = bi * f.numerator / f.denominator;
```